# Rails and asset hosts with SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to have my website on both http and https using the request object as in the documentation: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html

I've tried many configurations and many combinations, right now this is what I have in my environment/staging.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request=nil|
if request && request.ssl?
  "https://staging.foobar.it"
else
  "http://assets#{ ( source.length % 4 ) + 1 }.staging.foobar.it"
end
}
```

with this solution it appears like the request object is always set at nil.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.12, with nginx as reverse proxy and unicorn as app server, and precompiling my assets

Has someone been able to configure this and have the https website link to the right https asset server? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the nginx config for the relevant site set to serve assets statically?

Comment: Yes, it is. Is it relevant? ...

Comment: It means your assets are being served by nginx NOT your Rails app

Comment: Do you solved your issue?